# Create Url in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have created a custom Url in `Yii2` using

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,

            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

                    'site/GetNewTicketsTechnician' => 'site/get-new-tickets-technician',

            ),
        ]
```

in web.php(I am using basic template).

But when I try to create a url using

```
yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/get-new-tickets-technician'])
```

It is generating url as `site/GetNewTicketsTechnician` and not as

```
site/get-new-tickets-technician .
```

Can anybody knows the correct method to generate a url in `Yii2` ?

Comment: And that this should work. Did you read documentation? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that last rule (`'site/GetNewTicketsTechnician' => 'site/get-new-tickets-technician'`). It has `site/get-new-tickets-technician` as target route, so when you use it with `Url::to()` it will be used in reverse.

If you need that url to be callable (you have incoming requests on it), but don't want to include it for `createUrl`-statements (generating links), you'll have to configure it as parse only:

```
[
   'mode' => \yii\web\UrlRule::PARSING_ONLY,
   'pattern' => 'site/GetNewTicketsTechnician',
   'route' => 'site/get-new-tickets-technician'
]
```